# Manipulating file in PHP without $_FILES

Tags: php, image, file, upload, gd

I'm trying to programmatically add a tint to an image. I've done this very easily with a form and the $_FILES array but I need to get the image from a URL, and the images I'm trying to use are on my own server if that is important. Here's a sample code of the working form function

```
$img = new Upload($_FILES['imgfile']);
```

Now all I need is something like `$img = new Upload(fopen($image_path);` But this isn't working... Please help me!!

Comment: Does this `Upload` class perform the image manipulation too? Seems strange and is a violation of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, you are passing a $_FILES array structure to your Upload class:

```
$img = new Upload($_FILES['imgfile']);
```

The variable `$_FILES['imgfile']` itself is an array, consisting of named members such as `'name'`, `'tmp_name'` and others - information about the file that has been passed to PHP by the server receiving the uploaded file.

Your `Upload` class appears to be designed to handle this sort of structure.  It will probably have been designed specifically for handling file uploads, so you may need to modify it a bit to allow it to be passed any file path as a parameter instead of this array structure.

Comment: Actually I figured it out, I just needed the server address to the image instead of having the $_FILES['imgname']; there

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can fake $_FILES array all right.
the only function you cannot fool with this array is move_uploaded_file() but it seems you don't need it anyway.

but, you know, nobody have an idea what your "new Upload" is.